# How can i add a single dynamic key to a type in TS?

Tags: typescript, api, generics, types, interface

i am trying to do the following

Assume there is a rest endpoint that returns something like

/users

```
{
  pages:20,
  pageSize : 10,
  users: [array of users]
}
```

/employees

```
{
  pages:20,
  pageSize : 10,
  employees: [array of employees]
}
```

Obviously the pages and pagesize properties are constant for everything. But the one property containing the entity data changes

What i want to do, is make a fetch function, that given the name "customers" or "users" or anything provided dynamically, will return the appropriate object in a type safe way

So providing fetch("**users**") should return an object which has the recognized properties **pages, pageSize and users**

Thanks

Comment: Why not just have a base interface `interface Pageable { pages: number, pageSize: number}` which you just extend later like `interface PageableEmployees extends Pageable { employees: Employee[] }`? You might be able to make it a generic but it's a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Well i am going to write at least 20 of them so i was looking for a way to automate this

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] that others can drop into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to demonstrate the issue for themselves and test any potential answer against.  What types are "users" and "employees" supposed to be?  Where is the mapping from the word "users" to the type in the array?

Comment: It *could* look something like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mZaGoN) but I had to guess about the types.  Does that work for you?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, please elaborate about what doesn't work, ideally with [mcve] that shows use cases.

Comment: This code works great, it's exactly what i was trying to make. Thanks. Create an answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get dynamically the interface or type name but the nearest thing that you can do is this:

```js
type Person = {
    name: string,
    surname: string
}

type PaginationType = {
    page: number
    pageSize: number
}

type PaginableData<T> = PaginationType & {
    data: Array<T>
}


let foo: PaginableData<Person>
```

in order to do a function that uses this types and gives you back the name of the data you can use this:

```js
type Person = {
    name: string,
    surname: string
}

type PaginationType = {
    pages: number
    pageSize: number
}

type PaginableData<T> = PaginationType & {
    [key: string]: Array<T>
}


let foo: PaginableData<Person>


async function fetchData<T>(dataName: string): Promise<PaginableData<T>> {
    const response = await fetch(`/${dataName}`)
    const { body } = await response.json()
    const { pages, pageSize } = body
    return { pages, pageSize, [dataName]: body[dataName] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this out without testing but the idea is use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and make a generic factory function.

```
interface Pageable {
    page: number
    pageSize: number
}

function genericFetch<T extends Pageable>(apiUrl: string, guardFn: (maybeT: unknown) => maybeT is T): Promise<T> {
    return fetch(apiUrl)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json()
            } else {
                throw new Error("fail")
            }
        })
        .then((json: unknown) => {
            if (guardFn(json)) {
                return Promise.resolve(json)
            } else {
                throw new TypeError("fail")
            }
        })
}
```

e.g.

```
interface Users extends Pageable {
    users: Array<User>
}

function isUsers(maybeUsers: unknown): maybeUsers is Users {
    // Be as precise as you need it to be. Perhaps you need to
    // iterate over the users array to also check each array item
    // is a valid user.
    return isPlainObject(maybeUsers) && "users" in maybeUsers
}

genericFetch("/users", isUsers)
    .then(data => {
        // data is Users
    })
    .catch(/* ... */)
```